# Create CDMA (3gpp2) PDU in Android

Tags: java, android, cdma, pdu

I asked a similar question last week and even set a bounty on it, after realizing the problem was the answer given was for a [GSM PDU (3gpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/1443717) and it worked flawlessly in the emulator (android 2.2). I accepted the Answer and awarded the bounty, and changed the title for future reference.

**Question:**

Now, I'm asking how to create a CDMA (3gpp2) PDU, similar to creating a [GSM PDU (3gpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/1443717), that can be parsed in Android's API `createFromPdu()`

**Trying to avoid writing it my self:**

I was excited when reading the new method [createFromPDU(byte[] pdu, String format)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/provider/Telephony.java#Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)
then realized that wouldn't be backwards compatible.

I was even curious of using `com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);` using the GSM PDU generated from the [original question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338541/1443717). But I'm not quite sure if that would be safe...

So I've decided the best way would be either create a GSM or CDMA PDU depending on the type of device.

Does anyone have a snippet laying around that can create a CDMA PDU?

Or know how to convert the method creating a GSM PDU to a CDMA PDU format?

**UPDATE:**

I've been working on manually creating a method to create a CDMA (3gpp2) pdu
I've gotten close to getting success following the [awesome breakdown of a cdma pdu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11401421/1443717)
But I can't seem to understand how to 7bit pack the `BearerData` and cat the date string to the end of the pdu properly, this is what I have so far

```
private static byte[] createCDMAPDU(String sender, String body) {

    byte[] pdu = null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(100);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

    Date now = new Date ();
    byte[] dateBytes = new byte[6];
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    dateBytes[0] = (byte) (asBytes(""+calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))[0]);
    dateBytes[1] = (byte) (asBytes(""+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)[0]);
    dateBytes[2] = (byte) (asBytes(""+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))[0]);
    dateBytes[3] = (byte) (asBytes(""+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))[0]);
    dateBytes[4] = (byte) (asBytes(""+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))[0]);
    dateBytes[5] = (byte) (asBytes(""+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND))[0]);

    try {
        dos.write(0);// unknown padding
        dos.write(0);// unknown padding
        dos.write(0);// unknown padding
        // MESSAGE_TYPE_POINT_TO_POINT = 0x00;
        // MESSAGE_TYPE_BROADCAST = 0x01;
        // MESSAGE_TYPE_ACKNOWLEDGE = 0x02;
        dos.write(0x00);// message type - MESSAGE_TYPE_POINT_TO_POINT
        // TELESERVICE_NOT_SET = 0x0000;
        // TELESERVICE_WMT = 0x1002;
        // TELESERVICE_VMN = 0x1003;
        // TELESERVICE_WAP = 0x1004;
        // TELESERVICE_WEMT = 0x1005;
        dos.writeInt(0x1002); // teleservice - TELESERVICE_NOT_SET
        // dos.writeInt(0); // servicePresent
        dos.writeInt(0); // serviceCategory
        // DIGIT_MODE_4BIT_DTMF = 0x00;
        // DIGIT_MODE_8BIT_CHAR = 0x01;
        dos.write(0x01);// digit mode - DIGIT_MODE_4BIT_DTMF
        // NUMBER_MODE_NOT_DATA_NETWORK = 0x00;
        // NUMBER_MODE_DATA_NETWORK = 0x01;
        dos.write(0x00);// number mode - NUMBER_MODE_NOT_DATA_NETWORK
        // TON_UNKNOWN = 0x00;
        // TON_INTERNATIONAL_OR_IP = 0x01;
        // TON_NATIONAL_OR_EMAIL = 0x02;
        // TON_NETWORK = 0x03;
        // TON_SUBSCRIBER = 0x04;
        // TON_ALPHANUMERIC = 0x05;
        // TON_ABBREVIATED = 0x06;
        // TON_RESERVED = 0x07;
        dos.write(0x00); // number_type - TON_UNKNOWN
        // NUMBERING_PLAN_UNKNOWN = 0x0;
        // NUMBERING_PLAN_ISDN_TELEPHONY = 0x1;
        dos.write(0x0);// number plan - NUMBERING_PLAN_UNKNOWN
        dos.write(sender.length());// number of digits
        dos.write(sender.getBytes(), 0, sender.getBytes().length); // digits
        dos.write(0);// bearer reply ?
        dos.write(0);// bearer reply ?
        // Subaddress is not supported.
        dos.write(0); // subaddressType
        dos.write(0); // subaddr_odd
        dos.write(0); // subaddr_nbr_of_digits
        // dos.write(encodedBearerData.length);
        // dos.write(encodedBearerData, 0, encodedBearerData.length);
        dos.write(0);
        dos.write(0);
        dos.write(0);
        dos.write(0);
        dos.write(0);
        byte[] bodybytes = getAsciiBytes(body);
        dos.write(bodybytes.length);
        dos.write(0);
        dos.write(0x03);
        dos.write(0x10);
        dos.write(0);
        dos.write(bodybytes, 0, bodybytes.length);
        dos.write(0);
        dos.write(dateBytes.length);
        dos.write(dateBytes);
        dos.close();

        pdu = baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return pdu;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: Hi we meet again. You can try using `reflection` to get this [`createPdu()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/cdma/SmsMessage.java#716) method. `mEnvelop` created from  [`newFromParcel`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/cdma/SmsMessage.java#136). And the last [`ril.cpp`](http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/hardware/ril/libril/ril.cpp?r=334#2055) they mention

Comment: @Yul Any chance you can add to the progress I've made, manually creating it? (I'm not entirely sure If I'm even on the right track) But I figured I'd try to avoid reflection as much as possible. Unless you can finish it with reflection, I'd accept that too.

Comment: I haven't work with Android for a while. I'll add answer if i find something interesting :).